# How to clear last @Input variable values ? Angular 2+

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I use changeDetection strategy and it works ok but when my component is destroy when I come back I have the last value saved.

Example I props 3 values to child component and went to another component when i try again to prop data i see my last values ..

Example props values 1 , 2 and 3.
I see my last values 3.
How to destoy it ?

Check code and parent component:

```
  <div class="row"> 
   <app-poi-address [poiPin]="pinedAddress"></app-poi-address>
  </div>
 this.pinedAddress = $event;
```

Child component:

```
@Component({ 
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class PoiAddressComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {
  @Input () poiPin!: Object
  public allPin: any[] = [];
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log('datica' , this.poiPin);
  }

  ngOnChanges(): void {
    console.log('HelloComponent: Change Detection count = ' , this.poiPin);
    this.allPin.push(this.poiPin)
  }

}


<div *ngFor="let d of allPin  ">
    <p> {{  d?.coords?.lat }} </p>
</div>
```

Saved last values. I want to clear all array of allPin...

Comment: You could just initialize it in ngOnInit

Comment: What ? I need ngOnChange because i push on click items... ? I don't understand what you say?

Comment: Is the parent of PoiAddressComponent destroy too? If not, the parent keeping the last value of pinedAddress, when next time PoiAddressComponent recreate again the last pinedAddress pass to PoiAddressComponent too, so you will get the last value "3".

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts.

Comment: I need it don't worry

Comment: If you would like to add a solution, do so using the "answer" button at the bottom. Questions are for questions, not for vandalism, answers, or other content. Keep in mind once you post content here, you license it under CC By SA 4.0; you no longer "own" it like you might expect.

Answer (score 1):

This would clear your all pin variable on when recreating the component after desctruction.

```
 ngOnInit(): void {
     allPin = [];
     console.log('datica' , this.poiPin);   
}
```

Comment: Ah wrong button, it was supposed to be code formatting. Thanks!